# Puppeteer JS giving 504 gateway timeout on Centos 7

Tags: puppeteer, centos7

I'm getting a 504 gateway time out error, [this was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69152586/puppeteer-504-gateway-time-out-error-in-production):
But there is no solution.

I'm running this on Centos 7.

I've installed all the packages recommended from the Puppeteer JS Centos 7.

```
try {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] })
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.freecodecamp.org/');
  
  await browser.close();
  res.send('it launched 94!')
} catch (e) {
    res.send(`got an error ${e}`);
  console.info("Unable to launch browser mode in sandbox mode. Lauching Chrome without sandbox.");
  
}
```

I never hit the `res.send('it launched')`, nor do I get the catch block.

Log reports:

```
6466/Tc age/Cor/App/Gro/SessionManagement.cpp:330: Session checked out from process (pid=27554, group=/var/www/vhosts/inkto.art/preview.inkto.art (production))
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.20.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "debug": "~4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "node-html-to-image": "^3.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "puppeteer": "^19.11.1",
    "resolve-path": "^1.4.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.5.0"
  }
```

Server running on CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 (Core).

I followed the yum install instructions from Puppeteer JS.

UPDATE: Running on Ubuntu works.  But not Centos 7.